# How to get system time in Haskell using Data.Time.Clock?

Tags: haskell, systemtime

I'm needing some `Int`s to use as seed to random number generation and so I wanted to use the old trick of using the system time as seed.

So I tried to use the Data.Time package and I managed to do the following:

```
import Data.Time.Clock

time = getCurrentTime >>= return . utctDayTime
```

When I run time I get things like:

```
Prelude Data.Time.Clock> time
55712.00536s
```

The type of `time` is `IO DiffTime`. I expected to see an `IO Something` type as this depends on things external to the program. So I have two questions:

a) Is it possible to somehow unwrap the IO and get the underlying DiffTime value?

b) How do I convert a DiffTime to an integer with it's value in seconds? There's a function `secondsToDiffTime` but I couldn't find its inverse.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> Is it possible to somehow unwrap the IO and get the underlying DiffTime value?

Yes.  There are dozens of tutorials on *monads* which explain how.  They are all based on the idea that you write a *function* that takes `DiffTime` and does something (say returning `IO ()`) or just returns an `Answer`.  So if you have `f :: DiffTime -> Answer`, you write

```
time >>= \t -> return (f t)
```

which some people would prefer to write

```
time >>= (return . f)
```

and if you have `continue :: DiffTime -> IO ()` you have

```
time >>= continue
```

Or you might prefer `do` notation:

```
do { t <- time
   ; continue t  -- or possibly return (f t)
   }
```

For more, consult one of the many fine tutorals on monads.

Comment: I'd think for simplicity, especially for a beginner, you could omit the parenthesis in return . f and whow the whitespace-style do-syntax?

Comment: @codebliss: for a beginner I wanted to make things very explicit and so not require the reader to understand the details of operator precedence or layout

Comment: You can also do `f <$> time` since every monad is a functor. IMO this looks very nice.

Comment: iiuc, that's not unwrapping; it's keeping it wrapped in a monad and doing things inside the monad.  And not everyone finds monadology to be trivial.

Answer (score 9):

a) Of course it is possible to get the `DiffTime` value; otherwise, this function would be rather pointless. You'll need to read up on monads. [This chapter](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/monads.html) and [the next](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/programming-with-monads.html) of Real World Haskell has a good introduction.

b) The [docs for `DiffTime`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/time/1.1.4/doc/html/Data-Time-Clock.html#t%3ADiffTime) say that it's an instance of the `Real` class, i.e. it can be treated as a real number, in this case the number of seconds. Converting it to seconds is thus a simple matter of chaining conversion functions:

```
diffTimeToSeconds :: DiffTime -> Integer
diffTimeToSeconds = floor . toRational
```

Comment: You lose the picoseconds this way, however.  I usually do `truncate . (fromIntegral precision * ) . toRational . utctDayTime`, which gives you the number of picoseconds.  (And for seeding a RNG, using this value lets you have more than one initial state per second, which is important in many applications.)

Comment: (oh, and precision = 10000000000000)

Answer (score 9):

If you are planning to use the standard `System.Random` module for random number generation, then there is already a generator with a time-dependent seed initialized for you: you can get it by calling `getStdGen :: IO StdGen`.  (Of course, you still need the answer to part (a) of your question to use the result.)

Answer (score 1):

This function is not exactly what the OP asks. But it's useful:

```
λ: import Data.Time.Clock
λ: let getSeconds = getCurrentTime >>= return . fromRational . toRational . utctDayTime
λ: :i getSeconds 
getSeconds :: IO Double     -- Defined at <interactive>:56:5
λ: getSeconds 
57577.607162
λ: getSeconds 
57578.902397
λ: getSeconds 
57580.387334
```